# jquery datables plugin and dynamic object name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, calendar, datatables

I struggling with [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to fill my table.
The problem i have is that when i get my google calendars in this format

```
{"23gjsd91su3guu509o1bchhqms@group.calendar.google.com":{"calendar_id":"23gjsd91su3guu509o1bchhqms@group.calendar.google.com","calendar_title":"#1612 White Quartz Apartment"},"vqbidsn2u4edlvto0frvevk6ig@group.calendar.google.com":{"calendar_id":"vqbidsn2u4edlvto0frvevk6ig@group.calendar.google.com","calendar_title":"#994 Cisco Amber (T2)"},"bi07i6futd90lvq9ba8ufvqdu8@group.calendar.google.com":{"calendar_id":"bi07i6futd90lvq9ba8ufvqdu8@group.calendar.google.com","calendar_title":"#1443. Marley Blue"}}
```

Need help on put datatables to work with this.
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3):

You must sanitize the JSON so it is ordered on the form `[{item}, {item}, ..]` :

```js
function sanitizeData() {
    result  = [];
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        result.push(data[key]);
    })
    return result;
}
```

Then, if you have table like this

```html
<table id="example"></table>
```

You can now populate a dataTable with the content of the JSON this way :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data : sanitizeData(),
    columns : [
        { title : 'id', data : 'calendar_id' },
        { title : 'title', data : 'calendar_title' }
    ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zbuudydv/1/**